# Clojure Ring wrap-reload is not working

Tags: clojure

This is my core.clj file

```
(ns lein-app.core
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]))

(use 'ring.adapter.jetty)

(defroutes app
  (GET "/" [] "<h1>Hello world</h1>")
  (route/not-found "<h1>Not found</h1>"))

(def reloadable-app
  (wrap-reload app))

(defn -main
  []
  (run-jetty reloadable-app {:port 3000}))
```

And this is my project.clj

```
(defproject lein-app "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
    [compojure "1.5.2"]
    [ring "1.5.0"]]

  :main lein-app.core)
```

When I run lein run it starts the server correctly but if I change the GET response to be anything else for example I need to kill the server and restart it.

Comment: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/issues/104

Comment: but mine isn't off by a request. it doesn't update at all.

Comment: so `(wrap-reload #'app)` does not solve your problem ?

Comment: it does! but how..

Comment: it's explained in the issue - `wrap-reload` needs to capture the `var` itself, not its value to be able to reload - this is a pattern you'll find with many "live-reload" functions in different projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as indicated in the ring [issue#104](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/issues/104) the doc is not quite clear.

For `wrap-reload` (as well for similar functionality in other libs/projects) one has to pass the var itself not the value.

Like so

```
(wrap-reload #'app)
```