# How to make wrap-reload work for generated routes?

Tags: clojure, ring

I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074428/clojure-ring-wrap-reload-is-not-working) that `wrap-reload` from `ring` needs to capture the `var` itself not the value, but what if my value is dynamically generated and not a top level `var`?

```clj
(defn -main [options]
  (let [app (make-app options)]
    ;; This won't work either:
    ;; (run-jetty (wrap-reload #'app))
    (run-jetty (wrap-reload app))
  ))
```

Comment: I think this does not work.  You want to run `make-app` at some point to create the new app.  So I'd leave the main for what it is now and put a `(def app (make-app ["-p", "8080"]))` or whatever in user.clj and a bit of tooling to start/stop jetty for REPL/reload (or opt in for one of the reload workflows).

Comment: @cfrick sure that's one workaround. Since `wrap-reload` works based on namespace, I suppose there is a solution if we can find the namespace of a `var?` in let bindings.

Comment: I don't think it can pickup a change to `make-app` without calling it again.

Comment: haha, that's really a good point!  I guess I'll just use that workaround now. Thanks @cfrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clojure `let` bindings do not create a `Var` object, so you cannot use the trick of passing `(var app)` (or it's shortcut `#'app`) in place of the function object that `app` points to.

Please see the following for more detail:  [When to use a Var instead of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function)

Comment: I find the top answer to that question especially helpful, thanks!